# Mediawiki Internal error when saving templates

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

everyone,
I am trying to create a template for mediawiki so that's what i am doing:

1. creating a new page called Template:test
2. put "{{{1}}}" as text
3. save

then I get an Internall Error page 
 with text:

> [ca127b174f26a5c978fe0ec0]
>   /index.php?title=Template:Test&action=submit Error from line 1777 of
>   /var/www/public_html/includes/parser/Preprocessor_DOM.php: Cannot use
>   object of type StripState as array
>
> Backtrace:
>
> 0 /var/www/public_html/includes/parser/Parser.php(3776): PPCustomFrame_DOM->getArgument(string)
>   1 /var/www/public_html/includes/parser/Preprocessor_DOM.php(1194): Parser->argSubstitution(array, PPCustomFrame_DOM)
>   2 /var/www/public_html/includes/parser/Parser.php(2931): PPFrame_DOM->expand(DOMElement, integer)
>   3 /var/www/public_html/extensions/TinyMCE_MW/TinyMCE_MW.php(264): Parser->replaceVariables(string, PPCustomFrame_DOM)
>   4 /var/www/public_html/includes/Hooks.php(195): wfTinymceParserPaste(Parser, string)
>   5 /var/www/public_html/includes/parser/Parser.php(1413): Hooks::run(string, array)
>   6 /var/www/public_html/includes/parser/Parser.php(450): Parser->internalParseHalfParsed(string, boolean, boolean)
>   7 /var/www/public_html/includes/content/WikitextContent.php(330): Parser->parse(string, Title, ParserOptions, boolean, boolean, NULL)
>   8 /var/www/public_html/includes/content/AbstractContent.php(497): WikitextContent->fillParserOutput(Title, NULL, ParserOptions, boolean,
>   ParserOutput) 
>   9 /var/www/public_html/includes/page/WikiPage.php(2198): AbstractContent->getParserOutput(Title, NULL, ParserOptions) 
>   10 /var/www/public_html/includes/page/WikiPage.php(1717): WikiPage->prepareContentForEdit(WikitextContent, NULL, User, string,
>   boolean) 
>   11 /var/www/public_html/includes/EditPage.php(2144): WikiPage->doEditContent(WikitextContent, string, integer, boolean,
>   User, string, array) 
>   12 /var/www/public_html/includes/EditPage.php(1470): EditPage->internalAttemptSave(array, boolean) 
>   13 /var/www/public_html/includes/EditPage.php(612): EditPage->attemptSave(array) 
>   14 /var/www/public_html/includes/actions/EditAction.php(59): EditPage->edit() 
>   15 /var/www/public_html/includes/actions/SubmitAction.php(38): EditAction->show() 
>   16 /var/www/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(495): SubmitAction->show() 
>   17 /var/www/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(289): MediaWiki->performAction(Article, Title)
>   18 /var/www/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(851): MediaWiki->performRequest()
>   19 /var/www/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(512): MediaWiki->main() 
>   20 /var/www/public_html/index.php(43): 
>   MediaWiki->run() 
>   21 {main}

Comment: It has something to do with one of the editor extentions I think. It worked ok after I commented out configs for "TinyMCE_MW" and "Wiki Editor"

Comment: Extensions are [marked as unmaintained](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TinyMCE_MW) for a reason.